# Google analytics stopped showing trackbacks after tracking code change

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, social-media, referrer

We have a pretty heavily linked-to website. GA showed some trackback in Acquisition > Social > Trackbacks every day until a few days ago, then all the sudden nothing. There's data in other report pages under Social, such as Network Referrals. We made below changes right before it stopped working:

- Going from `ga.js` to `analytics.js` for universal tracking
- Enabled Enable Demographics and Interest Reports
- Enabled Enhanced link attribution
- Place same tracking code on all pages, including a subdomain

Any ideas how to get this data back?

Current tracking code:

```js
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-43531210-2', 'auto');
  ga('require', 'displayfeatures'); // Enable Demographics and Interest Reports
  ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js'); // enhanced link attribution
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

[image: GA]

Comment: Wow, you made/manage Bower? Cool. Thanks. :)

The new roll out of GA is having its fair share of issues, so much so that Justin Cutroni (one of the Google Evamgelists working on Analytics) has shared a [form on his G+ stream][1].


  [1]: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1T8CKgkV88xGjGxMd-0kzowAPpJB8S4w8-nxwZmXPdJc/viewform

Comment: Thank you @Prasad. It's a community effort and I'm just a tiny part of it :) I've submitted via that form, and will try to reach Justin.

Comment: Is this report still broken for you?   I checked my Universal Analytics enabled property and it has some trackbacks listed.  I don't use either the demographics or enhanced links products though.

Comment: Hi @StephenOstermiller & Prasad, I was able to fix this by tweaking "Social Content URL Prefix". Please see my answer. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be "Social Content URL Prefix", which is under Admin - Property - Social Settings. We entered a few social URLs, e.g. twitter, facebook, etc. This setting states "by entering one or more prefixes ... will only get social activities against those domains". We didn't enter our main domain, which caused all social activities against our domain (e.g. Trackbacks) to be filtered out. Clearing this setting worked.